# Input Accessory View is showing over objects like UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

I'm using an Input Accessory View the following way.

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return self.userInputView
}
```

Also, at the viewDidAppear method, i'm putting:

```
let _ = self.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This is a must in my case because my viewController is a childViewController.

Anyway, i don't know why, but when i'm presenting a UIAlertController and the keyboard is active, the keyboard goes down, the inputAccessoryView also disappears and then shows up suddenly above the UIAlertController.

Anyone experienced something like that?

Thanks

Edit - Added picgture:
[image: Shows over the UIAlertController]

Comment: If you post image it will be easy to understand

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This will fix..!

**Do not use the name 'inputAccessoryView**

`- (UIView *)CustominputAccessoryView {
    if (!keyboardinputAccessoryView) {
        CGRect accessFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 40.0);
        keyboardinputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:accessFrame];
        keyboardinputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor  colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:0.6];
        UIButton *compButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        compButton.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-60, 0.0, 50, 40.0);
        [compButton setTitle: @"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        compButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [compButton setTitleColor:self.view.tintColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [compButton addTarget:self action:@selector(completeCurrentWord:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [keyboardinputAccessoryView addSubview:compButton];
    }
    return keyboardinputAccessoryView;
}`

keyboardinputAccessoryView is just a UIView

```
@property (readonly, retain) UIView *keyboardinputAccessoryView;
```

then make 'CustominputAccessoryView' as inputAccessoryView of your textField

```
    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
 textField.inputAccessoryView = [self CustominputAccessoryView];
}
```